# Adapter отображает только первый элемент

Tags: android

В активити А я вызываю активити Б, в котором получаю данные для создания элементов. Но почему-то адаптер отображает только один элемент (который создается самым первым).

Код активити А:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<Items> elements;
private TaskAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    elements = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new TaskAdapter(elements);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Intent intent = data;

    Items item = (Items) intent.getSerializableExtra(Items.class.getSimpleName());

    if (item.getTask() != null) {
        elements.add(item);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public void floatinButton1OnClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddElement.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

Код активити Б:

```
public class AddElement extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_element);
}

public void floatingButton1OnClick(View view) {

    TextView tvTask = findViewById(R.id.task);
    TextView tvComment = findViewById(R.id.comment);

    String task = tvTask.getText().toString();
    String comment = tvComment.getText().toString();
    String firstDate = new String();
    String secondDate = new String();
    ArrayList<String> subtasks = new ArrayList<>();

    Items item = new Items(task, comment, firstDate, secondDate, subtasks);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Items.class.getSimpleName(), item);

    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Код Адаптера:

```
public class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.TaskViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Items> elements;
Context context;

public TaskAdapter (ArrayList<Items> elements){
    this.elements = elements;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public TaskViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    context = parent.getContext();
    int LayoutIdForListItem = R.layout.example_of_item1;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(LayoutIdForListItem, parent, false);

    TaskViewHolder viewHolder = new TaskViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TaskViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return elements.size();
}

class TaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView task;
    Button button;

    public TaskViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        task = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task);
        button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

    void bind(final int position) {

        task.setText(elements.get(position).getTask());

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setMessage(elements.get(position).getComment())
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }).create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Может у вас условие `if (item.getTask() != null)` не срабатывает?

Comment: попробовал убрать это условие, но ничего не меняется

Comment: Ну... Давайте гадать. 1. Метод onActivityResult у вас не вызывается. 2. Активити какими-то флагами запуска обозначена в манифесте и имеет некорректное состояние. 3. Intent неправильно составлен. Попробуйте просто `Intent intent = new Intent()` во второй активити использовать. \\\\ Ну и дайте больше информации, чтобы не пришлось гадать. Залоггируйте всё и вся и/или пройдитесь дебаггером чтобы локализовать проблему - что именно и в какой момент имеет некорретное состояние или не вызывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что мой layout файл, который является образцом для элементов списка, имел параметр `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, его необходимо заменить на `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`